# use bash alias in system builtin function in awk

Tags: awk, macos

I need to run the following:

```
SOME_OTHER_COMMAND | awk '{system("MY_BASH_PROFILE_ALIAS some stuff "$1" some other stuff")}'
```

but when running the above i get the following error:

```
sh: MY_BASH_PROFILE_ALIAS: command not found
```

is there a way to run my `alias` located in `.bash_profile` in the `system` awk function? Or is there an alternative to achieve the same thing?

Comment: AWK `system()` function cannot run user-defined functions/aliases. and it uses `sh` shell for executing the commands in `system("command")`

Comment: Tell system to run `bash` with what ever options are needed to source your config (`.bashrc`). I assume there is more in the real `awk` script.

Comment: If you could add what your `awk` code is doing as well as what your alias is doing, it would probably be easy for us to suggest what the correct way of resolving your issue would be.

Comment: its exactly that what i want to do, given a previous commands output, i want to process it with awk to select a certain column from output and place it as input in my custom bash alias. the custom alias calls an installed package located in /usr/local/bin/PACKAGE